# Install MediaWiki with PostgreSQL instead of MySQL

Tags: apt, 10.04, configuration, mediawiki

I need to install MediaWiki with PostgreSQl as database backend on an 10.04 server.

I would prefer to install MediaWiki via apt-get/aptitude but I don't know how to configure the installation not to install the unneeded MySQL.

Is it possible to change the dependencies from MySQL to PostgreSQL and if yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
apt-get --ignore-depends install <pkg>
```

This will ignore all dependencies the only problem is that MySQL may not be the only one.  So to avoid that I would suggest:

```
apt-get -d install <pkg>
```

Then once all the packages are downloaded.  Install each one individually doing:

```
dpkg --ignore-depends <individual package>
```

Personally I think installing MySQL and then simply reconfigure MediaWiki to use PostgreSQL if it is possible might be a better solution.